# Is there any way to change the name of a USB camera?

Tags: linux, camera, usb

I'm using a USB camera on a Rp4, here are the details

```
P: /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/video4linux/video1
N: video1
L: 0
S: v4l/b,y-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-video-index1
S: v4l/by-id/usb-HD_USB_Camera_HD_USB_Camera_2020042001-video-index1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/video4linux/video1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/video1
E: MAJOR=81
E: MINOR=9
E: SUBSYSTEM=video4linux
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3888323105
E: ID_V4L_VERSION=2
E: ID_V4L_PRODUCT=HD USB Camera: HD USB Camera
E: ID_V4L_CAPABILITIES=:capture:
E: ID_VENDOR=HD_USB_Camera
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=HD\x20USB\x20Camera
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=32e4
E: ID_MODEL=HD_USB_Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=HD\x20USB\x20Camera
E: ID_MODEL_ID=4689
E: ID_REVISION=4104
E: ID_SERIAL=HD_USB_Camera_HD_USB_Camera_2020042001
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=2020042001
E: ID_TYPE=video
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:0e0100:0e0200:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=uvcvideo
E: ID_PATH=platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_3_1_0
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=video4linux-platform-fd500000_pcie-pci-0000_01_00_0-usb-0_1_3_1_0
E: COLORD_DEVICE=1
E: COLORD_KIND=camera
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/v4l/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-video-index1 /dev/v4l/by-id/usb-HD_USB_Camera_HD_USB_Camera_2020042001-video-index1
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
```

Is there any way to change the `ID_V4L_PRODUCT` or `ID_VENDOR` or `ID_MODEL` variable ?
My goal is to identify which camera is plumed on the Rp4, so my Qt software can adapt itself. I will have different known camera hardware

PS : They come from [ELP](http://www.webcamerausb.com/) company

Comment: Question: How did you produce this output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-v4l.rules` file with the following content (change `ID_VENDOR_ID` and `ID_MODEL_ID` values to match your setup):

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="046d", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0825", ENV{ID_V4L_PRODUCT}="Logitech C270 Webcam"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0c45", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="648b", ENV{ID_V4L_PRODUCT}="Laptop Integrated Webcam"
```

Use `udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/video0)` command to test your configuration.